# Full Index Rebuild with 5M documents on Elastic search 7.6 takes 1 week to complete

Tags: elasticsearch, reindex, rebuild

Hope all are doing well

Currently Elastic 7.6 is running on cluster with 3 nodes and it's having 5M records in it.

While performing the Full rebuild of indexed is taking huge amount of time. But other server metrics like CPU and GC is within the limit

And similarly I had tried  ES re index process which is also time consuming. Applied few workarounds like by setting Refresh interval to -1 and Replica to 0 but it still takes very long time.

I have almost 168 shards bt the segment count is lil more which is showing 800+.

Kindly help and suggest to resolve this issue. Any leads would be much appreciated.

Comment: How much memory is allocated to the node? What is the number of CPU cores available in the machine where node runs? What type of disk is on the machine SSD / HDD ?

Comment: Its 16 core Vcpu with 54 GB RAM on each node. And the Disk type is Block volume storage. I have assigned 26 GB to Heap.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, it looks like you have some bad configuration of cluster, nodes, and important indexing related setting which is causing this much slow performance.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try the settings suggested by you and will update here if any improvement occur.

Comment: @Neha did you find any improvement??